# Calculate absolute difference between values in two columns

Tags: r, absolute-value

I'm writing a R code to count/select the rows with absolute difference of two values in two columns less than a certain value (say 0.1). It reads two files and two column numbers, based on which the calculation is done.

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
f1<-args[1]
f2<-args[2]
col1<-args[3]
col2<-args[4]

if (length(args) <4) {
    stop("\n\nUsage: file1 file2 column1 column2 >output\n\n")
}
pearsoncor<-function(in1,in2,x,y){
# Read in data
file1<-read.table(in1,header=F)
file2<-read.table(in2,header=F)
col1<-as.integer(x)
col2<-as.integer(y)

# Calculate pearson correlation

    cor_r <- which(file1[,col1] != '.' & file2[,col2] != '.')
    file1.filter<-file1[cor_r,col1]
    file2.filter<-file2[cor_r,col2]
    x=cor.test(c(file1.filter),c(file2.filter),method="pearson")
    fname=paste(basename(in1), " and ", basename(in2),sep="")
    print(fname)
    print(x)
    conc_c <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(cor_r)) 
    {
        dif<-abs(file1.filter[i,] - file2.filter[i,])
        if (dif <0.1){
            conc_c = conc_c +1
        }
    }
    print(conc_c)
}

pearsoncor(f1,f2,col1,col2)
```

Test files: two test files that are tab delimited.

```
==> t1.txt <==
chr1    10468   10470   .       1       +       chr1    10468   10470   0.762   2
chr1    10470   10472   .       2       +       chr1    10470   10472   0.738   2
chr1    10483   10485   .       3       +       chr1    10483   10485   0.865   2
chr1    10488   10490   .       4       +       chr1    10488   10490   0.825   2
chr1    10492   10494   .       5       +       chr1    10492   10494   0.894   2
chr1    10496   10498   .       6       +       chr1    10496   10498   0.859   2
chr1    10524   10526   .       7       +       chr1    10524   10526   0.954   2
chr1    10541   10543   .       8       +       chr1    10541   10543   0.876   2
chr1    10562   10564   .       9       +       chr1    10562   10564   0.829   2
chr1    10570   10572   .       10      +       chr1    10570   10572   .   2

==> t2.txt <==
chr1    10468   10470   .       1       +       chr1    10468   10470   0.69    2
chr1    10470   10472   .       2       +       chr1    10470   10472   0.7     2
chr1    10483   10485   .       3       +       chr1    10483   10485   0.911   2
chr1    10488   10490   .       4       +       chr1    10488   10490   0.894   2
chr1    10492   10494   .       5       +       chr1    10492   10494   0.714   2
chr1    10496   10498   .       6       +       chr1    10496   10498   0.857   2
chr1    10524   10526   .       7       +       chr1    10524   10526   0.984   2
chr1    10541   10543   .       8       +       chr1    10541   10543   0.955   2
chr1    10562   10564   .       9       +       chr1    10562   10564   0.981   2
chr1    10570   10572   .       10      +       chr1    10570   10572   0.979   2
```

To run:

```
Rscript script.r t1.txt t2.txt 10 10
```

I couldn't get the absolute value calculation done in the code.. it gave this error:

```
Error in `[.default`(file1.filter, i, ) : incorrect number of dimensions
Calls: pearsoncor.jgu -> [ -> [.factor -> NextMethod
Execution halted
```

Also the first line of the error message came from here:

```
> file1.filter[1,]
Error in `[.default`(file1.filter, 1, ) : incorrect number of dimensions

> dput(head(file1.filter))
c(0.762, 0.738, 0.865, 0.825, 0.894, 0.859)
```

Answer (score 2):

`file1.filter` and `file2.filter` are both vectors, so the syntax `file1.filter[i,]` is causing an error and could be corrected by simply using `file1.filter[i]` (you would also need to use `file2.filter[i]`).

That being said, all you are doing with the `for` loop is counting the number of times where two vectors' elements differ by no more than 0.1:

```
conc_c <- 0
for (i in 1:length(cor_r)) 
{
    dif<-abs(file1.filter[i,] - file2.filter[i,])
    if (dif <0.1){
        conc_c = conc_c +1
    }
}
print(conc_c)
```

This could be accomplished in a single line in R:

```
print(sum(abs(file1.filter - file2.filter) < 0.1))
```

Basically `abs(file1.filter - file2.filter) < 0.1` returns the vector of whether each element is less than 0.1 apart and `sum` adds 1 for every `TRUE` value and 0 for every `FALSE` value, effectively summing the number of `TRUE` values in the vector.

Comment: thanks for the help. there is a bit more issue on my end. i only put 10 lines as a test file but the real file has millions of lines and file1.filter<-file1[cor_r,col1] gave me something not a vector.. it has levels..

Comment: i think that is because certain lines have . in the 10th column

Comment: so i guess i can use the answers from this post to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information

Comment: @olala We really can't help you with debugging issues unless you provide reproducible examples.

Comment: sorry, i realized that.. i just chanced the 10th column in last line of t1.txt, that can reproduce my issue now.. sorry about that. can you take a look? thanks! @josilber

Comment: i got this to work:  print(sum(abs(as.numeric(paste(file1.filter))-as.numeric(paste(file2.filter))) < 0.1))